# How to change text font that works in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, fonts, uitextfield

I am working on an appllication where i have to use calculator font for my UITextfield. I have installed that font in my mac and i have changed font of textfield from nib but it is not working when i check it in iPhone simulator. The output I want is this [image]

any body have an idea?

after setting font its result is like
[image]

Comment: most probably your label is covered by something....make the container's size larger or try bringing label to the front

Comment: i am not using separate label. this is text field and i have tried to change its size but in vain. well when i change its font then it becomes normal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing the font on Mac is not enough. You have to embed the font into your app. Here is a tutorial on how to achieve this. Good Luck:

http://kgriff.posterous.com/45359635

Basically it says:

> CUSTOM FONTS IN IOS. Your designer has given you this super snazzy
>   custom font for your app. Now what?!
>
> iOS 4 makes it easy to include custom fonts in your projects. Drop the
>   file (CloisterBlack.ttf) into your project.  Open up your Info.plist
>   file, create a key called UIAppFonts and make it an array. Add the
>   filename of the font as a value.
>
> UIAppFonts 
>           CloisterBlack.ttf  Wherever you want
>   to use the font in your application you can call:
>
> [UIFont fontWithName:@"CloisterBlack" size:64.0] Hum not quite, when I
>   fired up my application I was met the the same old font - what gives?
>
> Turns out (in my case) I should not be referencing the font by the
>   value I supplied to my plist file. I opened my font in Font Book, and
>   the 'name' has a good 'ol space in it.
>
> [UIFont fontWithName:@"Cloister Black" size:64.0] Anyway that's 20
>   minutes I'll never get back.

Comment: Perfect one well now a new problem is occurring. when my text is not in editing mood then some text from bottom is cutting